# How to add a point to leaflet that should be on map but invisible?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

When displaying search results, one often wants to see all results as well as the requested element on the same map.

To do that, I add the searched point to the same layer and use the `fitBounds` method as follows :

```
map.fitBounds(markerLayer.getBounds().pad(0.10));
```

Now, the problem is my marker is still visible on the map and it should not be. Is it possible to hide/toggle visibility of a single marker?

Tried so far :

- Setting the opacity at 0. The marker is indeed not visible but the cursor still changes on hover and you can still click it.
- Setting the requested city marker in separate layer. Useless as you cannot get the bounds of multiple layers AND even if you group those layer in a `LayerGroup`, you cannot get the bounds of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the opacity of a marker:

```
markerLayer.setOpacity(0);
```

(see http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setopacity)

---

**Edit:**

If you don't want it to be clickable, you can use the `clickable` option when you create the marker:

```
var markerLayer = L.marker([0, 0], { clickable: false });
```

(see http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-clickable)

Comment: That works but the item is still clickable and the pointer changes on hover.

Comment: Yes, because the question specifically asks about toggling *visibility*. If you want it to look **and** behave as if it's not there, the simplest option is surely to remove the marker from the map? `map.removeLayer(markerLayer)`

Comment: No because, that means, I will lose all points of my layer which I don't want. And you cannot get the bounds of multiple layers...

Comment: In Leaflet, a marker is a layer. A layer doesn't have points. Each point is displayed as a marker, and each marker is it's own layer that can be 'toggled' by passing it to `map.addLayer()` or `map.removeLayer()`.

Comment: Oh, nice. Didn't knew that a simple marker was a layer. That makes it easy indeed !